# Python OAuth Client Credentials Grant Type Returned 400, [error: unsupported grant] type but Curl Works Fine

Tags: python, curl, oauth, python-requests

I am very new to APIs (still learning) and I encountered a very weird issue with Python `requests` library when trying to initiate an OAuth Authentication flow with **Client Credentials Grant Type**.

For some reason, whenever I used my Python script (with the help of `requests` library) to send the HTTP request to the authentication endpoint, I always get

```
Response Status Code: 400
Response Body/Data returned: {"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}
```

However, if I tried using `curl` command line tool to send the request, I will get a **successful response with status code 200 with the access token in the response body** like this:

```
{'access_token': 'some access token', 
 'expires_in': 'num_of_seconds', 
 'token_type': 'Bearer'}
```

As a matter of fact, ***if I tried sending the request using Curl command line tool WITHIN my Python Script (with `subprocess.Popen` function), I can get the response with status code 200 and the access token with no problem***.

Now, with that said, here's the Python script that I used to send the request to initiate the OAuth authentication flow:

```
import requests 
import os
import base64

clientCredentialEndpoint = "https://base_url/path/token"
client_id = os.environ.get('CLIENT_ID')
client_secret = os.environ.get('CLIENT_SECRET')

# -- Encode the <client_id:client_secret> string to base64 --
auth_value = f'{client_id}:{client_secret}'
auth_value_bytes = auth_value.encode('ascii')
auth_value_b64 = base64.b64encode(auth_value_bytes).decode('ascii')


queryParams ={
    'grant_type':'client_credentials',
    'scope':'get_listings_data'
}

headers = {
    'Authorization':f'Basic {auth_value_b64}',
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

# send the post request to Authorisation server
response = requests.post(
    clientCredentialEndpoint,
    params=queryParams,
    headers=headers,
)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

whereas the curl command that I used (and worked) to send the request is:

```
curl -X POST -u '<client_id>:<client_secret>' \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-d 'grant_type=client_credentials&scope=get_listings_data' \
'https://base_url/path/token'
```

Again, like I said, if I execute this curl command inside a Python script, it will successfully return the access token with no issue.

Does anyone know what I did wrong in my Python script which caused my request to always fail?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

My goodness me, I just realised that the `-d` in the curl command does not correspond to query params, it stands for **'data'**.

Hence, I just need to change my Python script `requests.post()` a bit so that it looks like this:

```
response = requests.post(
    clientCredentialEndpoint,
    data=queryParams,
    headers=headers,
)
```

Hope this helps others.